# GitLab CI/CD Pipeline - How to output the console logs of a job (Maven) as an artifact to download

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I am currently creating a CI/CD pipeline in GitLab and have some jobs that run maven commands e.g.

```
maven test-compile:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn clean test-compile
```

These are simple console commands but I want to output the logs created by the runner to a file that can be downloaded as an artifact WHILST also keeping the logs in the console whilst the pipeline is running.

I attempted the following which output the logs to a file but by directing them to a file the logs were not shown and I had to tail the logs to circumvent this:

```
  script:
    - mvn clean test-compile > log.txt
    - tail -f ./log.txt
```

Is there a simpler way to get around this?

Many thanks

```
  script:
    - mvn clean test-compile > log.txt
    - tail -f ./log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @CsNova and welcone on SO

The frst thing is to pipe your output and use tee. This will print the build  on stdout AND into the file

`mvn clean test-compile | tee log.txt`

Then you can add a step in you pipeline to save this artifact (https://apps.risksciences.ucla.edu/gitlab/help/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.md#defining-artifacts-in-gitlab-ciyml)

```
pdf:
  script: xelatex mycv.tex
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - mycv.pdf
    expire_in: 1 week
```